# Comparing all items of one list present in another and in same order

Tags: python

In the following code, how do I return only those values as True, where order of elements in checklist is followed in routelist?

For eg:
`checklist(["BOMH","DELH","BRGH"])` should return as True `["BOMH","CCUH","DELH","BRGH"]` but not `["BOMH","BRGH","CCUH","DELH"]`.

```
def checklhcost2(checklist):
    thcdataselect["shortlist"] = thcdataselect.apply(lambda x:\
                True if all((i in x["routelist"] for i in checklist)) else False)
    return thcdataselect.filter_by(1,"shortlist")
```

Comment: As a side note, `True if all((i in x["routelist"] for i in checklist)) else False` is exactly equal to `all(i in x["routelist"] for i in checklist)`. Other than that, I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> chk = ["BOMH","DELH","BRGH"]
>>> one = ["BOMH","CCUH","DELH","BRGH"]
>>> two = ["BOMH","BRGH","CCUH","DELH"]
```

Make a set for membership testing

```
>>> set_chk = set(chk)
```

Generator expressions to filter AND maintain order

```
>>> one_a = (thing for thing in one if thing in set_chk)
>>> two_a = (thing for thing in two if thing in set_chk)
```

Use zip to pair up items in `chk` and the target lists for comparison.

```
>>> all(a == b for a, b in zip(chk, one_a))
True
>>> all(a == b for a, b in zip(chk, two_a))
False
```

To ensure all items are present as well as in the correct order, use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

```
>>> three = ['BOMH', 'CCUH', 'DELH']
>>> three_a = (thing for thing in three if thing in set_chk)
>>> 
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> 
>>> all(a == b for a,b in zip_longest(chk, three_a))
False
>>>
```

Using `zip` would have produced an incorrect result:

```
>>> all(a == b for a,b in zip(chk, three_a))
True
```

---

Or just make new, filtered lists and compare.

```
>>> one_a = [thing for thing in one if thing in set_chk]
>>> two_a = [thing for thing in two if thing in set_chk]
>>> three_a = [thing for thing in three if thing in set_chk]

>>> one_a == chk
True
>>> two_a == chk
False
>>> three_a == chk
False
```

Comment: Thanks wwii! this makes the problem look so easy. What I finally did using your tips was:
define a function which returns a list:
def setthings(x,y):
    z = [i for i in y if i in x]
    return z

and check for exact match of the list:
 thcdataselect.apply(lambda x:True if setthings(checklist,x['routelist'])==checklist else False)

Answer (score 2):

Use a mapping to determine the weight of each value, filter out the ones that don't match, and check that it's ordered properly:

```
master = ["BOMH","DELH","BRGH"]
ordering = {item:idx for idx,item in enumerate(master)}
check1 = ["BOMH","CCUH","DELH","BRGH"]
check2 = ["BOMH","BRGH","CCUH","DELH"]

def check(o, c):
    return all(o[i]==r for i,r in zip((i for i in c if i in o), range(len(o))))
```

Result:

```
>>> check(ordering, check1)
True
>>> check(ordering, check2)
False
```

Comment: Thanks @TigerhawkT3! This was an intelligent way of doing it and worked like a charm. Small comment for the benefit of others:

The code checks the ordering but not whether all items of ordering are present in check1/check2 so you will need to also have the line from my original code:
all((i in check1 for i in ordering))

Answer (score 1):

```
def checklhcost2(values):
    expected_seq = ["BOMH","DELH","BRGH"]
    # for each element in expected_seq get index from values
    L = [values.index(v) if v in values else -1 for v in expected_seq]
    # if indexes are in increasing order and >1 then return True
    return all(x<y and x > -1 for x, y in zip(L, L[1:]))

checklhcost2(["BOMH","CCUH","DELH","BRGH"])
#True
checklhcost2(["BOMH","BRGH","CCUH","DELH"])
#False
```

It also works on edge cases where expected_seq has values which the input parameter doesn't example

```
expected_seq = ["BOMH","DELH","BRGH", "other"]

checklhcost2(["BOMH","CCUH","DELH","BRGH"])
#False
checklhcost2(["BOMH","BRGH","CCUH","DELH"])
#False
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a good solution, but it seems it works.

```
>>> checklhcost2 = lambda chl: reduce(lambda x,y: x and routelist.index(y[1]) == y[0], enumerate([ itm for itm in chl if itm in routelist]), True )
>>> checklhcost2(["BOMH","CCUH","DELH","BRGH"])
True
>>> checklhcost2(["BOMH","BRGH","CCUH","DELH"])
False
>>>
```

The main idea is quite simple: filter out everything which is not in routelist, then enumerate the rest and check indexes. Return logical and of match for all indexes (reduce function).